# The following series converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis

Does the following series coverge or diverge?

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log\log n}}$$

My attempts :  I know  that $\log(\log n) > 2$

So $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log\log n}}\le\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n)^{2}}\le\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$

so the given series converges.

Is it correct?

Comment: Check your inequalities, $\ln n<n$ !!!

Comment: Since the terms are decreasing you can use the integral test.  A simple substitution ($y=\log x)$ will make it clear that the integral diverges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's incorrect. We don't have $\log n \ge n$.

Instead, $(\log n)^{\log \log n} = \exp((\log \log n)^2) \le \exp(((\log n)^{1/2})^2) = n$ for $n \ge N_0$, so $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {(\log n)^{\log \log n}} \ge C + \sum_{n=N_0}^\infty \frac 1 n = \infty$$

---

Implicit result used: $\log x \le x^\varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $x$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The series is divergent. Note that $a_n= \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log\log n}}=\exp(-(\log\log n)^2)$ is positive and decreasing and, by [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), the convergence of the given series is equivalent to the convergence of
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n\exp(-(\log\log 2^n)^2)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \exp(n\log 2-(\log n+\log\log 2)^2)$$
which is divergent because $n\log 2-(\log n+\log\log 2)^2\to +\infty$.